# Diagonalizable Matrix with polynom

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, diagonalization

Let $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ be a diagonalizable matrix and let $f(x)$ be a polynom with $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove: f(A) is diagonalizable.

How can I prove this? Do I need to verify the determinant, rank etc?

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All you need to do is to use the fact that, if $P$ is invertible,$$f(PAP^{-1})=Pf(A)P^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jose Carlos, but I dont understood this exactly. A diagonalisierbar
If A is diagonalizble I can write it as
D = P^-1 * A * P <=>
P * D = A * P <=>
P * D * P^-1 = A <=>
f(P*D*P^-1) = f(A) From this step how can I conclude it? Do I have to use linearity?

Comment: If $D$ is diagonal and $D=P^{-1}AP$, then $f(D)=P^{-1}f(A)P$. But $f(D)$ is diagonal, too.

Comment: ahh thats true then it makes sense!